# Android Studio compiler error R.java

Tags: android, android-studio

I have added this line of code to my program:

```
    icon1.setImageResource(getResources().getIdentifier(item1, "drawable", getPackageName()));
```

And have added images (.png) to my drawable folder. When I compile I get the following error:

```
Error:(773, 32) error: <identifier> expected
Error:(773, 37) error: illegal start of type
```

The error location in R.java:

```
public static final class drawable {
        public static final int 1001=0x7f020000;
        public static final int 1004=0x7f020001;
        public static final int 1006=0x7f020002;
        public static final int 1011=0x7f020003;
        public static final int 1018=0x7f020004;
        public static final int 1026=0x7f020005;
        public static final int 1027=0x7f020006;
        ..........
```

Each one of those throws its own pair of those errors.

I'm putting the images into the /res/drawable-hdpi folder.

What could be the cause of this?

Comment: Try: `icon1.setImageResource(getResources().getIdentifier("icon_name", "drawable", getApplicationContext()));`

Comment: @BobMalooga The problem with that is the value item1 I am using is variable. How would I handle that in that situation?

Comment: Replace "icon_name" with the name of your variable, which in turn, is a string containing the name of your resource. Done.

Comment: @BobMalooga So essentially what I already have, just changing the last bit from getPackage() to getApplicationContext()?

Comment: Yes. Obviously, the name doesn't have to contain "R.drawable" and nor the extension (".*") - it's **just the file name**.

Comment: @BobMalooga With this:             icon1.setImageResource(getResources().getIdentifier(item1, "drawable", getApplicationContext()));
 I'm running into an issue where it wants a String as the last parameter, not Context.

Comment: Sorry! I went by memory... This will fix it: `getApplicationContext().getApplicationInfo().packageName`

Comment: @BobMalooga Same issue occurs. I'll edit more details into my main post. Perhaps I'm adding the images wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android Studio compile error with added resouces](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23417440/android-studio-compile-error-with-added-resouces)

Comment: What are the names of your resources? do they contain invalid characters such as UpperCase letters, "-" or they start with a number?

Answer (score 2):

Filenames can't start with numbers, just add any letter prefix to your files and it will work.

Reason is R.java is generating variables using filenames, and in C# or any decent programming language you can't declare a variable starting with digits.