# Android Studio compile error with added resources

Tags: android, android-studio

I have added this line of code to my program:

```
icon1.setImageResource(getResources().getIdentifier(item1, "drawable", getApplicationContext().getApplicationInfo().packageName));
```

And have added images (.png) to my drawable folder. When I compile I get the following error:

```
Error:(773, 32) error: <identifier> expected
Error:(773, 37) error: illegal start of type
```

The error location in R.java:

```
public static final class drawable {
        public static final int 1001=0x7f020000;
        public static final int 1004=0x7f020001;
        public static final int 1006=0x7f020002;
        public static final int 1011=0x7f020003;
        public static final int 1018=0x7f020004;
        public static final int 1026=0x7f020005;
        public static final int 1027=0x7f020006;
        ..........
```

Each one of those throws its own pair of those errors.

I'm putting the images into the /res/drawable-hdpi folder. Is the issue that the file names are all numeric (ex. 1023.png)?

What could be the cause of this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The lines like:

```
public static final int 1001=0x7f020000;
```

are saying "declare a variable with type `int` whose name is `1001` and whose value is `0x7f020000`". Names should be identifiers (consisting of the characters `a`-`z`, `A`-`Z` or `_`, with `0`-`9` being allowed only after the first character).

In this instance, `1001` is an integer not an identifier, which is why you get the " expected" error. The "illegal start of type" error is referring to the same issue (the compiler is expecting an identifier to provide the name of the type).

The items in `R.java` should be things like:

```
public static final int actionbar_logo=0x7f020000;
```

The drawable identifiers are created from the filenames and as you have numeric filenames it is using those values. You should give the images sensible names or append a prefix to them, e.g. `r1023`.

Comment: nice catch for the `0-9` could not be the first character